# No crash report received in GA

Tags: android, google-analytics, uncaught-exception

I want to receive crash report in Google Analytics for my android app. I added the code :

```
<bool name="ga_reportUncaughtException">true</bool>
```

in my analytics.xml.

I'm using SDK V4. When an uncaught exception is thrown I'm not receiving any crash report in my account's property ID. 
I also used the below code right after initializing tracker in my onCreate() method.

```
UncaughtExceptionHandler myHandler = new ExceptionReporter(resetActivityTracker,Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(),this); 
Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(myHandler);
```

I get the following lines in my log

```
04-10 18:34:14.527: V/GAV3(19414): Thread[main,5,main]: Tracking Exception: BadTokenException (@ResetActivity$operationTask:onPreExecute:158) {main}
04-10 18:34:14.537: V/GAV3(19414): Thread[main,5,main]: Passing exception to original handler.
```

after which my runtime exception (i.e uncaught exception) is logged as usual

```
04-10 18:34:14.547: E/AndroidRuntime(19414): FATAL EXCEPTION: main .......
(error details)
```

What is it I'm missing in order to get crash report in my account. Can someone provide me with full code to handle uncaught exception and to display in my account?

Comment: I have the same problem. Were you able to solve it?

Comment: @Marty I tried with V3 SDK. It worked!